# unable to add a new row into the table current rows

Tags: reactjs

> I am trying to add a new row into the table rows. Here 'rows' has the data of the table.

```
    const newRows = [...rows];
    const newData=[{videos:youtubeURL},{status:'Online'},{model:4},{manage:49},{device:'Lam6'}, 
    {favourite:false}]
    setResults({ Results: newRows.concat(newData) }); // This gives error ! I don't the correct approach
```

> Remaining code

```
    const [Results, setResults] = React.useState(rows);

     function createData(videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite) {
      return { videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite };
       }
     const rows = [
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Cam1', true),
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Offline', 2, 37, 'Am2', true),
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Zam3', false),
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Offline', 2, 67, 'Dam4', false),
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 49, 'Lam5', false),
     ];
```

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is React.useState() and not just useState()?

Comment: Yes, Michael ! React.useState works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine and it works as expected. See the below attached code snippet with results.

```js
function createData(videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite) {
  return { videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite };       }
const rows = [
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Cam1', true),
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Offline', 2, 37, 'Am2', true),
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Zam3', false),
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Offline', 2, 67, 'Dam4', false),
     createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 49, 'Lam5', false),
];
console.log("Number of records before concat:");
console.log(rows.length);
const newRows = [...rows];
const newData=[{videos:'youtubeURL'},{status:'Online'},{model:4},{manage:49},{device:'Lam6'},{favourite:false}]
console.log("Number of records after concat:");
console.log(newRows.concat(newData).length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The react component with state is attached below to show that code works fine with React state as well.

```
import React from 'react';

class TestReact extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.updateResults = this.updateResults.bind(this);
        this.createData = this.createData.bind(this);
        this.rows = this.rows.bind(this);
        this.state = {results: this.rows()}
    }

    rows() {
      return [
        this.createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Cam1', true),
        this.createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Offline', 2, 37, 'Am2', true),
        this.createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Zam3', false),
        this.createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Offline', 2, 67, 'Dam4', false),
        this.createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 49, 'Lam5', false),
      ]
    }
    
    createData(videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite) {
      return { videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite };
    }

    updateResults() {
      const newRows = [...this.rows()];
      const newData=[{videos:'youtubeURL'},{status:'Online'},{model:4},{manage:49},{device:'Lam6'},{favourite:false}]
      this.setState({ results: newRows.concat(newData) }); 
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <>
            <button onClick= { () => this.updateResults()}>Click me to concat records</button>
            <div>
              {this.state.results.length} Records
            </div>
          </>
        )
    }
}

export default TestReact;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Deepak. But the problem is that I am navigating from one page to another and that is why cannot use onclick. My apologies if I could not state the question properly. If possible can you have a look at another post and suggest me the possible solution. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029433/uncaught-error-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-renders-to-preve

Comment: Your welcome! I will check and try to answer on that post. Thank you.