# Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

After navigation from one page to another page, I am trying to add a new row to the table of the page. The below code results in an infinite loop. How can I avoid it?

```
function createData(videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite) {
  return { videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite };
}
const rows = [
  createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Cam1', true),
  createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Offline', 2, 37, 'Am2', true),
  createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Zam3', false),
  createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Offline', 2, 67, 'Dam4', false),
  createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 49, 'Lam5', false),
];
export default function StreamPage(props) {   
  const [Results, setResults] = React.useState(rows);
  let youtubeURL = props.location.deviceRow;
  if (youtubeURL != null && youtubeURL != "") {
    const newRows = [...rows];
    const newData = createData(youtubeURL, 'Online', 4, 49, 'Lam6', false)     
    setResults(newRows.concat(newData))  //   Here I have infinite loop and error 
  }

  return ()
};
```

setResults() is called multiple times and as a result there is a loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> This is the fix that worked for me.

```
 setResults({ Results: Results.push(newData) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to avoid infinite loop:

```
// ...

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (youtubeURL != null && youtubeURL != "") {
    const newData = createData(youtubeURL, 'Online', 4, 49, 'Lam6', false)     
    setResults(prevRows => [...prevRows, newData])
  }
},[youtubeURL])

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ali but now after using React.useEffect 
'setResults(newRows.concat(newData))' is not adding a new row in the table. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you make sure that your `if` condition is meeting the criteria?

Comment: Yes if condition is working but I guess there is something wrong with the code 'setResults(prevRows => [...prevRows, newData])'.

Comment: Can you print your results in log and see if array is being updated. And can you paste the code where you're rendering the results array.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        if (youtubeURL != null && youtubeURL != "") {
            alert("in")
            const newRows= [...rows];
          const newData = createData(youtubeURL, 'Online', 4, 49, 'Lam6', false)     
         const x = newRows.concat(newData);
         console.log(x);
          setResults(x); 
        }
      },[youtubeURL]);

Comment: using this code x is upadated and the new row is added in the x but when I pass x to setResults then Results is not updated.

Comment: Where you're checking the updated results? if its in the next line then it shouldn't get updated results as `setState` is an async function. You'll get updated results outside `useEffect` and your component will re-rendered due to this effect.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        if (youtubeURL != null && youtubeURL != "") {
            alert("in")
            const newRows= [...rows];
          const newData = createData(youtubeURL, 'Online', 4, 49, 'Lam6', false)     
         const x = newRows.concat(newData);
         console.log(x);
          setResults(x); 
         // console.log(Results);
        }
      },[youtubeURL]);
      console.log(Results);

Comment: Results is not updated and the problem is if I use setResults() outside the useEffect then it will give infinite loop error.

Comment: In order to better facilitate, can you create a example on codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you very much Ali ! Really appreciate your time and help. I found the problem.